# Chrome syncFileSystem files deleted when uninstalling the app

Tags: google-drive-api, google-chrome-app

I'm making a chrome app using the syncFileSystem to store data.
I've noticed that if I uninstall the app, the files get deleted.

Is there a way to make them persist? An accidental uninstall by the user that deleted all his private data is a bad scenario in my case.

Comment: Are you creating a Google Drive App? Based on [this support ticket](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2523073?hl=en), your files will still be accessible in Google Drive, but you’ll no longer be able to use the app. In most cases, uninstalling a Google Drive app will remove its access to files in your Google Drive. Go to the "Authorizing applications & sites" section of accounts.google.com to double check.

Comment: Are there any logs or code snippets you can provide that can help resolve the issue?

Comment: I think the link you provided is about apps that open files that are already on your drive. I'm talking about syncFileSystem which generates a sandbox area, and seems to delete it when you uninstall the app. You can view a sample of this behavior if you install this sample app from google: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/syncfs-editor